# Error while opening jar file '/tmp/flink-web-/flink-web-upload'

Tags: java-8, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have created a CICD process to deploy my flink application in flink server.
CD pipeline is able to add jar successfully but unable to submit the Jar.
I checked CD logs and found `500 internal server error`
I checked in flink-server logs, there I found this error

```
Error while opening jar file '/tmp/flink-web-<someid>/flink-web-upload'
```

Below is the complete error stack trace

```
2020-10-23 15:16:10,344 ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler    - Unhandled exception.
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Error while opening jar file '/tmp/flink-web-<id>/flink-web-upload'
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.checkJarFile(PackagedProgram.java:531)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.loadJarFile(PackagedProgram.java:407)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.<init>(PackagedProgram.java:133)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.<init>(PackagedProgram.java:68)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram$Builder.build(PackagedProgram.java:590)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.utils.JarHandlerUtils$JarHandlerContext.toJobGraph(JarHandlerUtils.java:127)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.lambda$getJobGraphAsync$6(JarRunHandler.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while opening jar file '/tmp/flink-web-<id>/flink-web-upload'
at org.apache.flink.util.JarUtils.checkJarFile(JarUtils.java:57)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.checkJarFile(PackagedProgram.java:529)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/flink-web-<id>/flink-web-upload (Is a directory)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
at org.apache.flink.util.JarUtils.checkJarFile(JarUtils.java:54)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the jar was corrupted.

Check MD5 SUM for the local file and the one on the cluster.